# Unclear on new style of AngularJS factory notation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-services

I was looking at [this interesting piece on Angular best practices,](http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/) and decided I wanted to adopt some of these ideas as my own. However, his factory notation is something new to me - I haven't seen it before in any tutorials I've done. For reference, here's how he does it:

```
app.controller('InboxCtrl',
  function InboxCtrl ($scope, InboxFactory) {

  InboxFactory
    .getMessages()
    .then(function () {
      $scope.messages = InboxFactory.messages;
    });

});

app.factory('InboxFactory',
  function InboxFactory ($location, NotificationFactory) {

  InboxFactory.getMessages = function () {
    return $http.get('/messages')
    .success(function (data) {
      // magic line, we resolve the data IN the factory!
      InboxFactory.messages = data;
    });
  };

});
```

However, I'm struggling with this. I haven't been able to do it exactly as he did - not returning anything in the factory seems to make every call of `InboxFactor.something` error with `Cannot find property something of undefined`.

Here's my best attempt:

```
.factory( 'FormsOverviewFactory', function FormsOverviewFactory(apiForms) {
  FormsOverviewFactory.forms = []; 
  FormsOverviewFactory.asdf = function(){
    console.log("asdf",FormsOverviewFactory.forms);
  };  
  FormsOverviewFactory.getForms = function(){
          return apiForms
                  .forms()
                  .get()
                  .$promise.then(function (result){
                    FormsOverviewFactory.forms = result.data;
                    // THIS PRINTS THE CORRECT DATA
                    FormsOverviewFactory.asdf();
                  });
                };

  return{
    forms: FormsOverviewFactory.forms,
    asdf: FormsOverviewFactory.asdf,
    getForms: FormsOverviewFactory.getForms
  };
})

.controller( 'FormsOverviewCtrl', function FormsOverviewCtrl($scope, FormsOverviewFactory) {

  FormsOverviewFactory.getForms().then(function(){
    $scope.createdForms.forms = FormsOverviewFactory.forms;
    FormsOverviewFactory.asdf();
    // GIVES RIGHT STUFF
    console.log($scope.createdForms.forms);
    // GIVES []
  });
```

Comment: Looks nothing like how I write a factory.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the guys code was wrong.

Comment: @ZackArgylei agree on what you mentioned

Comment: How is this approach nicer/better? It is rather confusing. Why don't you stick to the normal notation?

Comment: The original code is incorrect. Factories must return something in order to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a typo in the code.

Based on the context, it seems that the author's intention is to return the factory function itself.
In your case, it would mean replace:

```
return {...}
```

with:

```
return FormsOverviewFactory;
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/PbsjM/)**.

---

In which case, I wonder why not just use `.service` instead of `.factory` and `this.something` instead of `FormsOverviewFactory.something` (and not have to return anything - the controller's code remains the same) ?

Comment: I've read great (as in "really interesting") posts from that guy, but I've also read some pretty bad/misleading/making-simple-things-sound-too-complicated kind of posts. With so many "experts" out there, you should always take what you read with a grain of salt. Just because someone wrote it on their blog, it doesn't mean it's right (but it could be of course :)).